# Slightly modifying base component template in Angular Component Inheritance scenario

Tags: angular, inheritance, components, angular2-template

I have an app which requires three different types of buttons (a basic button, a form button and a toggle button). Although it would certainly be possible to put everything into the same component (e.g. using attribute binding [attr.type] for the submit button and emitting a toggle event for the ToggleButton), I would like to keep them as three separate components, and I was thinking about doing this through component inheritance like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-basebutton',
  templateUrl: './basebutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basebutton.component.css']
})
export class BaseButtonComponent {   
  constructor() { }    
}
// Click listener etc...
```

The form button:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-formbutton',
  templateUrl: './formbutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formbutton.component.css']
})
export class FormButtonComponent extends BaseButtonComponent {   
  constructor() { }    
}
// Who knows? Some form properties or logic...
```

Finally, the toggle button:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-togglebutton',
  templateUrl: './togglebutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./togglebutton.component.css']
})
export class ToggleButtonComponent extends BaseButtonComponent {   
  constructor() { }    
}
// Some toggle properties and logic...
```

Extending the logic is pretty easy (and useful, although I've heard you can use TS mixins for this purpose nowadays).  Anyway, my question is, how can I reuse the BaseButton template, while still adjusting it according to each child button's need?

- If I use the base button's template, attribute binding would not be possible, because the BaseButton would not know (and should not know) about the child component properties. Obviously I want to keep the BaseButton as basic as possible and the derived buttons as "special" as possible.
- If I wrap the BaseButton element, I would be able to listen to the basic click event, but would not be able to change things like the button type or whichever other part of the BaseButton template without passing inputs.
- If I go for content projection, I would still have to write separate  elements. I only want to change a couple of attributes.
- If I wrap the BaseButton element and pass a TemplateRef as @Input(), I suspect that I also would have to repeat myself i.e. rewrite the  element, although I may just want to change an attribute or two.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, if they're worth making separate components, they're worth decoupling entirely (ie. no inheritance). Yeah, you might have to copy paste some code, and you might find that you want to make changes to both at the same time. But with inheritance, if ever you find the base component doesn't suit one of the extensions anymore, it's a real pain to modify in the future.

That being said, to achieve what you want you can use wrapper components.

**Form Button Template (app-formbutton)**

```html
<app-basebutton [buttonType]="'form'"></app-shared-button>
```

**Toggle Button Template (app-togglebutton)**

```html
<app-basebutton [buttonType]="'toggle'"></app-shared-button>
```

You can add click events and such to these wrapper components. You can also add things like borders / labels around the base button.

If you want to change the *inner* template you can use the `@Input() buttonType` property.

**Shared Template (app-basebutton)**

```html
<!-- Shared template stuff -->
<ng-container *ngIf="buttonType === 'form'">
    <!-- Form template here -->
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="buttonType === 'toggle'">
    <!-- Toggle template here -->
</ng-container>
<!-- Shared template stuff -->
```

If you don't want to mix different templates, you can create inner components.

```html
<!-- Shared template stuff -->
<app-inner-formbutton *ngIf="buttonType === 'form'"></app-inner-form-button>
<app-inner-togglebutton *ngIf="buttonType === 'toggle'"></app-inner-togglebutton>
<!-- Shared template stuff -->
```

The final result is just

```html
<app-formbutton></app-formbutton>
```

or

```html
<app-togglebutton></app-togglebutton>
```

There's no need to inherit from the base component, since it's nested within the wrapper. The downside to this is the complexity, and the fact that it's difficult for the inner template component to communicate with the wrapper. You may need a shared service, adding even more complexity. And of course the fact that the components are coupled meaning they can't evolve independently from one another.

I would say the simplest options are either

A) A single input variable that modifies the base template - like you mentioned at the start of the question or

B) Two entirely separate components